Python Flet AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_build_add_commands'
I'm currently working on my own project based on Flet's Trolli app example. My Flet version is 0.23.2. Trolli runs without any issues. I just made some modifications to the TrelloApp class in main.py, but some errors occur when running the program. Here is my code:
main.py
from app_layout import AppLayout

class App(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page
        self.page.on_route_change = self.route_change
        self.page.update()

    def build(self):
        self.layout = AppLayout(
            self,
            self.page,
            tight=True,
            expand=True,
            vertical_alignment="start",
        )
        return self.layout

    def initialize(self):
        # self.page.views.clear()
        self.page.views.append(
            View(
                "/",
                [self.layout],
            )
        )
        self.page.update()
        self.page.go("/")
        print("Initial route:", self.page.route)

    def route_change(self, e):
        troute = TemplateRoute(self.page.route)
        if troute.match("/"):
            self.page.go("/單人")
        elif troute.match("/單人"):
            self.layout.set_one_person_view()
        elif troute.match("/全部"):
            self.layout.set_all_people_view()
        self.page.update()


def main(page: Page):

    page.title = "更新資料"
    page.padding = 0
    # page.theme = Theme(font_family="Verdana")
    # page.theme.page_transitions.windows = "cupertino"
    app = App(page)
    page.add(app)
    page.update()
    app.initialize()
    print("Initial route:", page.route)


flet.app(target=main)


app_layout.py
from navigation_bar import NavigationBar
from scraper import Scraper

# from layout import Layout


class AppLayout(Row):
    def __init__(self, app, page: Page, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.app = app
        self.page = page
        self.navigation_bar = NavigationBar(self, self.page)
        self.navigation_bar.on_change = self.nav_change
        self.one_preson_view = Column(
            [
                TextField(
                    label="請輸入網址",
                    keyboard_type=KeyboardType.TEXT,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    text="檢查",
                    on_click=self.one_person_click,
                ),
                Text("", size=18),
            ],
            expand=True,
        )

        self.all_people_view = Column(
            [
                ListView(height=300, spacing=10),
                ElevatedButton(
                    text="檢查",
                    on_click=self.all_people_click,
                ),
                Row(
                    [
                        ElevatedButton(
                            "Pick files",
                            icon=icons.UPLOAD_FILE,
                            on_click=lambda _: self.pick_files_dialog.pick_files(
                                allow_multiple=False,
                                allowed_extensions=["csv"],
                            ),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            "delete data",
                            icon=icons.DELETE,
                            on_click=lambda _: self.delete_data(),
                        ),
                        Text(),
                    ]
                ),
                Text("", size=18),
                ListView(height=300, spacing=10),
            ],
            expand=True,
        )
        self._active_view: Control = (
            self.one_preson_view
        )  # 前面有底線，代表私有屬性，不能被直接訪問
        self.controls = [self.navigation_bar, self.active_view]
        self.pick_files_dialog = FilePicker(on_result=self.pick_files_result)
        self.selected_files = Text()
        self.page.overlay.extend([self.pick_files_dialog])
        self.scraper = Scraper(page, self.all_people_view.controls[3])
        self.set_one_person_view()
        self.update_url_lv()

    @property
    def active_view(self):
        return self._active_view

    # 屬性為setter，當設置active_view = value時，會執行此方法
    @active_view.setter
    def active_view(self, view):
        self._active_view = view
        self.controls[-1] = self._active_view
        # self.page.update()

    def one_person_click(self, e):
        print("one_person_click")
        if self.one_preson_view.controls[0].value == "":
            self.one_preson_view.controls[2].value = "請輸入網址"
        else:
            self.one_preson_view.controls[2].value = "檢查中..."
        # self.page.update()

    def all_people_click(self, e):
        print("all_people_click")
        self.all_people_view.controls[3].value = "檢查中..."
        self.page.update()
        self.scraper.getData(self.scraper.urlList)
        self.scraper.update(self.scraper.urlList)
        self.update_result_lv()

    def update_url_lv(self):
        self.all_people_view.controls[0].controls.clear()
        if self.page.client_storage.contains_key("local_urlList"):
            self.scraper.urlList = self.page.client_storage.get("local_urlList")
            for item in self.scraper.urlList:
                self.all_people_view.controls[0].controls.append(
                    Text(f"{item[1]}   {item[2]}")
                )
        # self.page.update()

    def update_result_lv(self):
        self.all_people_view.controls[4].controls.clear()
        for item in self.scraper.urlList:
            self.all_people_view.controls[4].controls.append(
                Text(f"{item[1]}   {item[2]}")
            )
        # self.page.update()

    # Pick files dialog
    def pick_files_result(
        self,
        e: FilePickerResultEvent,
    ):  # 傳入參數的形態是FilePickerResultEvent
        self.selected_files.value = (
            ", ".join(map(lambda f: f.name, e.files)) if e.files else "Cancelled!"
        )
        self.selected_files.update()
        self.update_data(e.files[0].path)
        self.update_url_lv()
        # self.page.update()

    def update_data(self, files):
        print("update_data")
        with open(
            files,
            mode="r",
            newline="",
            encoding="utf-8-sig",
        ) as f:
            self.scraper.urlList.clear()
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            next(reader)  # 跳過第一行標題
            for row in reader:
                self.scraper.urlList.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], "", ""])
            self.page.client_storage.set("local_urlList", self.scraper.urlList)

    def delete_data(self):
        self.scraper.urlList.clear()
        self.page.client_storage.set("local_urlList", self.scraper.urlList)
        self.page.client_storage.remove("local_urlList")
        self.update_url_lv()

    def set_one_person_view(self):
        self.active_view = self.one_preson_view
        # self.navigation_bar.selected_index = 0
        # self.page.update()

    def set_all_people_view(self):
        self.active_view = self.all_people_view
        self.active_view = self.all_people_view
        # self.navigation_bar.selected_index = 1
        # self.page.update()

    def nav_change(self, e):
        # print("Nav change:", page.navigation_bar.selected_index)
        if self.navigation_bar.selected_index == 0:
            # page.route = "/單人"
            self.page.go("/單人")
        elif self.navigation_bar.selected_index == 1:
            # page.route = "/全部"
            self.page.go("/全部")
        # self.page.update()

Normally, it should create an app window with an interface, but when I run the program, it only generates a blank window and gives the following error.
 Unhandled error processing page session : Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_runtime\app.py", line 244, in on_session_created  
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run  
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)  
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "d:\python_file\flet\flet_app\main.py", line 58, in main  
    page.add(app)  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\page.py", line 734, in add  
    r = self.__update(self)  
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\page.py", line 832, in __update  
    commands, added_controls, removed_controls = self.__prepare_update(*controls)  
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\page.py", line 848, in __prepare_update  
    control.build_update_commands(  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\control.py", line 464, in build_update_commands  
    ctrl.build_update_commands(  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\control.py", line 477, in build_update_commands  
    innerCmds = ctrl._build_add_commands(  
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\control.py", line 545, in _build_add_commands   
    childCmd = control._build_add_commands(  
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\control.py", line 545, in _build_add_commands  
    childCmd = control._build_add_commands(  
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\control.py", line 545, in _build_add_commands  
    childCmd = control._build_add_commands(  
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_build_add_commands' 

How can I fix the AttributeError?

Can you explain your problem a bit further? Also, is "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flet_runtime\app.py" your file or a library file? The error message you provided is weird and indeed looks like something is going on beyond your code. If the "app.py" is not your file but a library file, then I suspect an error with installation. If it is your file, then please also provide the code of it as well.

@LukeL 'app.py' is a library file. Normally, it should create an app window with an interface, but when I run it, it only generates a blank window and shows this error. In 'main.py' I import a class AppLayout written by myself, but other parts are similar to the example. I don't know if this is the problem. I added it to my question.
